# KeyError '/n' in Bio SeqUtils Package ProtParam Script

Tags: proteins, errors, biopython

I am trying to run a function from the ProtParam script in the Bio.SeqUtils package. The function is for calculating the instability index of a protein. The code I am using in my script with the pre-built function is the following:

```
# entry - user inputted string taking in amino acid letters
entry = e1.get()
prot_data = ProteinAnalysis(entry)
result = prot_data.instability_index()
```

When I run the code, I get the following key error related to the instability_index function.

```
File "/Genome_Toolkit/venv/lib/python3.9/site- packages/Bio/SeqUtils/ProtParam.py", line 152, in instability_index
dipeptide_value = index[this][next]
KeyError: '\n'
```

The instability_index() function in the ProtParam script looks like this:

```
def instability_index(self):
    index = ProtParamData.DIWV
    score = 0.0

    for i in range(self.length - 1):
        this, next = self.sequence[i: i + 2]
        dipeptide_value = index[this][next]
        score += dipeptide_value

    return (10.0 / self.length) * score
```

I looked at the script myself, specifically the line the error is referring to but couldn't pinpoint the issue. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

the output of `print(entry)` and `print(repr(entry))` looks like this, which is exactly what the entry was in the input:

```
MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYLVCGERGFFYTPKTRREAEDLQVGQVELGG
GPGAGSLQPLALEGSLQKRGIVEQCCTSICSLYQLENYCN
'MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYLVCGERGFFYTPKTRREAEDLQVGQVELGG\nGPGAGSLQPLALEGSLQKRGIVEQCCTSICSLYQLENYCN'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user is pushing `enter` on their keyboard, it is likely inserting a newline character (`\n`) at the end of the user input `entry` and causing the error you have included in your question. You can strip the `\n` by using `entry.rstrip('\n')`:

```py
# entry - user inputted string taking in amino acid letters
entry = e1.get()
entry = entry.rstrip('\n')
prot_data = ProteinAnalysis(entry)
result = prot_data.instability_index()
```

---

From the comments where the `print(entry)` was given as

> `MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYLVCGERGFFYTPKTRREAEDLQVGQVELGG GPGAGSLQPLALEGSLQKRGIVEQCCTSICSLYQLENYCN`

and `print(repr(entry))` is given as

> `'MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYLVCGERGFFYTPKTRREAEDLQVGQVELGG\nGPGAGSLQPLALEGSLQKRGIVEQCCTSICSLYQLENYCN'`

the `\n` character is not at the end of the line so `.rstrip('\n')` cannot be used (it only works at the end of the string).

Try instead `.replace('\n', '')`:

```py
# entry - user inputted string taking in amino acid letters
entry = e1.get()
entry = entry.replace('\n', '')
prot_data = ProteinAnalysis(entry)
result = prot_data.instability_index()
```

which on my system (removing the `prot_data` and `result` lines) outputs without the `\n` character and `print(repr(entry))` is the same as `print(entry)`.

Comment: @Z_Gonzalez rightttt, it's in the middle of the string, I just assumed as it was user input the `\n` was at the end, `.rstrip()` only works from the end of the string, we need to use `.replace()` instead, will edit the answer shortly